# $\left|x-1\right|=1-x$ solve the equation.

Tags: absolute-value

$\left|x-1\right|=1-x$

$\left|x-1\right| \Rightarrow \{ x-1, x\geq1; -x+1, x\lt1 \}$

When $x\geq1, x-1=1-x \Rightarrow 2x=2 \Rightarrow x=1$

When $x\lt1, -(x-1)=1-x \Rightarrow -x+1=1-x \Rightarrow 0=0$ so, true for all x

All I can do is just this.

I can't go any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real $a$ we have

$$a=|a| \iff a \ge 0.$$

Since $|x-1|=|1-x|$, we get

$$|x-1|=1-x \iff |1-x|=1-x \iff 1-x \ge 0 \iff x \le 1.$$

Comment: Oh, I can't understand it. Would not the equation $\left|x-1\right|=\left|1-x\right|$ is true when the expression $x-1\geq0$?

Comment: @ Muhammed Ç. TUFAN, its always the same and $\left|a-b\right|=\left|b-a\right|$, for example take $\left|2-3\right|=\left|3-2\right|$.

Comment: @Grothendieck Is this $\left|a-b\right|=\left|b-a\right|$ expression true for all conditions? I tried to use some different conditions but I they out the same result. Note: After I think about it a little more, I figured out that distance between two things never changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$|1-x|=|x-1|=1-x$;

$y:=1-x$; Then

$|y|=y$, or $y \ge 0$;

(Recall the definition of the abs. value)

$y=1-x \ge 0$;

$x \le 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @PeterSzilas! I got the idea why we are able to $1-x\geq0$.

Comment: Muhammed.Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$ case1: x>1 \implies|x-1| = x-1=1-x, so x =1$$
  $$ case 2: x<1 \implies|x-1|=1-x = RHS$$
$$\therefore$x= 1$\cup all x <1 $$

PS: Draw the graph of LHS and RHS to see it more clearly.

[image]

[image]